# how to apply sql query with a range of dates on crystal report

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have to retrieve of how many an employee attend to work between a range of two date.
I managed to get the query like this

ex date range : `2012-02-03` to `2012-03-03`

```
SELECT A.EmployeeD, A.EmployeeName, ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN  a.AttendanceDate BETWEEN '2012-02-03' AND '2012-03-03' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS AttendCount
FROM     (SELECT     EmployeeID, EmployeeName, AttendanceDate
                      FROM          dbo.tblAttendance
                      GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID, EmployeeName, AttendanceDate
         ) AS A
GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID, EmployeeName
```

but how do I use that so I can show it on Crystal Report (on C#) ?
I mean, I want user to be able to change the date range inside the program.

I usually use `select expert` feature for such thing but I don't think that will work for this, as far I as I know...
Can anyone help me? thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you able to get the info ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can offload the counting to CR...

1. Add the table 'tblAttendance' to your report
2. Create two parameters in the report, {?StartDate} and {?EndDate} that will contain your dates.
3. In your selection formula, add a line like this `{tblAttendance.AttendanceDate} in {?StartDate} to {?EndDate}`. At this point you have all the data you want, it's just a matter of displaying and summarizing.
4. Group by {tblAttendance.EmployeeID} and place a summary of `distinctcount({tblAttendance.AttendanceDate},{tblAttendance.EmployeeID})` in the GroupHeader or GroupFooter. This just means do a distinctcount() of attendance dates grouped by employee.
5. Display the summary, employee name, and employee ID on your report.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want! Thanks a lot! Sorry, I'm being too overexcited. I would've used dynamic dataset - which is really complex for me -, if you hadn't given me this solution. Thanks again.